# Quotient group with $\mathbb{Z}_2$ and $\mathbb{Z}_4$

Tags: group-theory, quotient-group

I recently published another question about quotient groups. In this case, I was practising and trying to find the elements of the group $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_4 / \langle(1,1)\rangle$. The progress made is the following:

Using Lagrange's theorem, since the group $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_4$ has 8 elements and $\langle (1,1)\rangle = \{ (1,1), (0,2), (1,3), (0,0) \}$ has 4 elements, there must be two elements inside the quotient group. One element is the equivalence class given by $[0]$, which is $\langle(1,1)\rangle$ itself. However, when adding $(1,2)$, which is not in the cyclic group $\langle(1,1)\rangle$ and $(0,1)$, which is neither in that group, one obtains $(1,3)$, which is in the cyclic group. Is there something wrong in my reasoning or the two elements of the quotient group are just the subgroup itself one and the other the rest of the elements? Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Well, you do agree that the quotient must be isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_2$, don't you?

Comment: There is no contradiction: if $x,y$ are not in a subgroup $H$, their sum can be in $H$.

Comment: Therefore, since we are using sum, it would not be a group, would it?

Comment: Exactly, I know that, but I see that the closure property is not applied in the final set

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for the mathematical formulas in your MSE posts. It isn't hard to learn and it makes your posts much more readable. As for the maths, $(1, 2) + (0, 1) = (1, 3)$ so $[(1, 2)] + [(0, 1)] = [(1, 3)] = 0$ in the quotient group, and that's fine. In fact $[(1, 2)] = [(0, 1)]$ and we expect $x + x = 0$ in a cyclic group of order 2.

Comment: Daniel, you should be thinking about the equivalence classes.

Comment: Sorry, I thought the language I had to use was LaTex. With that final fact you have written, now I understand what was happening. Thanks to all people who have answered

Comment: MathJax is the implementation of (a subset of) $\LaTeX$ that the MSE software supports.